# Subtracting row 2 from row 1 repeatedly

Tags: rstudio, subtraction

I want to create in R a column in my data set where I subtract row 2 from row1, row 4 from row 3 and so forth. Moreover, I want that the subtraction result is repeated for each row (e.g.if the result from the subtraction row2-row1 is -0.294803, I want this value to be present both in row1 and row2, hence repeated twice for both factors of the subtraction, and so forth for all subtractions).

Here my data set.

[image]

I tried with the function aggregate but I didn't succeed.
Any hint?

Comment: Please add the the program/language in your tags.

Comment: I just fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution 1

One way to that is with one simple loop:

([download mydata.csv](http://www.kleinbub.it/code/mydata.csv))

```
a = read.table("mydata.csv",header=T,sep=";")
a$delta= NA
for(i in seq(1, nrow(a), by=2 )){
  a[i,"delta"] = a[i+1,"delta"] = a[i+1,"log"] - a[i,"log"]
}
```

What is going on here is that the for loop iterates on every odd number (that's what the seq(...,by=2) does. So for the first, third, fifth, etc. row we assign to that row AND the following one the computed difference.
which returns:

```
> a
   su    match  log delta
1   1    match 5.80  0.30
2   1 mismatch 6.10  0.30
3   2    match 6.09 -0.04
4   2 mismatch 6.05 -0.04
5   3    match 6.42 -0.12
6   3 mismatch 6.30 -0.12
7   4    match 6.20 -0.20
8   4 mismatch 6.00 -0.20
9   5    match 5.90  0.19
10  5 mismatch 6.09  0.19
```

---

### solution 2

If you have a lot of data this approach can be slow. And generally R works better with another form of iterative functions which are the *apply* family.

The same code of above can be optimized like this:

```
a$delta = rep(
             sapply(seq(1, nrow(a), by=2 ),
                 function(i){ a[i+1,"log"] - a[i,"log"] }
             ),
          each=2)
```

Which gives the very same result as the first solution, should be faster, but also somewhat less intuitive.

---

### solution 3

Finally it looks to me that you're trying to use a convoluted approach by using the *long* dataframe format, given your kind of data.
I'd reshape it to *wide*, and then operate more logically with separate columns, without the need of duplicate data.

Like this:

```
a = read.table("mydata.csv",header=T,sep=";")
a = reshape(a, idvar = "su", timevar = "match", direction = "wide")
#now creating what you want became a very simple thing:
a$delta = a[[3]]-a[[2]]
```

Which returns:

```
>a
   su log.match log.mismatch delta
1  1      5.80         6.10  0.30
3  2      6.09         6.05 -0.04
5  3      6.42         6.30 -0.12
7  4      6.20         6.00 -0.20
9  5      5.90         6.09  0.19
```

The delta column contains the values you need. If you *really* need the long format for further analysis you can always go back with:

```
a= reshape(a, idvar = "su", timevar = "match", direction = "long")
#sort to original order:
a = a[with(a, order(su)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution can be:

```
x <- read.table("mydata.csv",header=T,sep=";")
x$diff <- rep(x$log[seq(2,nrow(x),by=2)] - x$log[seq(1,nrow(x),by=2)], each=2)
```

By using the function seq(), you can generate the sequences of row positions:

> 1, 3, 5, ... 9
>
> 2, 4, 6, ... 10

Afterwards, the code subtracts the rows 2...10 to the rows 1...9. Each result is replicated by using the command rep() and it's assigned to the new column diff.

Comment: Yay, that's an elegant solution!